# how to prevent gmail from being the default client with mailto links?

Tags: gmail, mailto

I'm using google chrome, is there some setting somewhere I can change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google's support site](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847):

1. Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings** > **Under the Hood**.
3. Click **Content settings**.
4. In the dialog that appears, find the “Handlers” section.
5. Click **Manage handlers**.
6. Select the handler you'd like to remove.
7. Click **remove this site**.

Comment: thanks and to switch to Apple Mail just follow what is in this post : wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Email-Client-on-Mac-OS-X